# Prevent textbox sending request on page load in Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I want to prevent a request sent by Livewire when my page is loaded. I am working with a search operation using Livewire.

**View**

```html
<div class="col-md-4 my-3">
    <input wire:model.debounce.500ms="search" 
           type="text" 
           placeholder="Search Permissions...." 
           class="form-control">
</div>
```

**Component**

```php
class ViewPermisson extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $search;

    protected $queryString = ['search'];
    protected $listeners = ['refreshPermissions' => '$refresh'];

    public function updatingSearch()
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $permissions = Permission::where('guard_name', 'admin')
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
            ->simplePaginate(10);
        
        return view('livewire.admin.access.view-permisson',
            ['permissions' => $permissions]);
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I load my page, Livewire input sends the request with an empty query string. I want to prevent this request on page load.

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin/permissions?
```

Here's a URL with an empty query string added when I am requesting a page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with while you rendering the page initially it return with the permission query. You should query the permission while the search field has been updated.

```
public $permissions;
    

public function updatedSearch()
{
    if($this->search == '') return;
    $this->permissions = Permission::where('guard_name','admin')->where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')->simplePaginate(10);    
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.admin.access.view-permisson');
}
```

Or you simply bypass the query by checking that the search variable is empty or not. like:

```
public function mount(){
    $this->search = '';
}

public function render()
{
    if($this->search != ''){
        $permissions = Permission::where('guard_name','admin')->where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')->simplePaginate(10);
        return view('livewire.admin.access.view-permisson',['permissions'=>$permissions]);
    }else{
        return view('livewire.admin.access.view-permisson',['permissions'=>null]);
    }  
    
}
```